# Foreach loop does not work as expected for getting data for the current week

Tags: c#

I have a problem the result of the dateAndTime save in the database is of type string in the following format 04/15/2020 but the result that I am getting from the database in slightly different in where I get something like Apr-15-2020 00000 can someone explains why is this happening and whether this is to do with the the format of the computer date.

```
        foreach(var week in totalNumberOfPublishedJobViaApiweek1_Of_CurrentMonth)
        {
           if(week.DateAndTime.Substring(0,2) == "01" || week.DateAndTime.Substring(0, 2) == "02" || week.DateAndTime.Substring(0, 2) == "03" ||
            week.DateAndTime.Substring(0, 2) == "04" ||  week.DateAndTime.Substring(0, 2) == "05"|| week.DateAndTime.Substring(0, 2) == "06" ||
            week.DateAndTime.Substring(0, 2) == "07")
            {
            countWeek1++;
            }else if(week.DateAndTime.Substring(0, 2) == "08" || week.DateAndTime.Substring(0, 2) == "09" || week.DateAndTime.Substring(0, 2) == "10" ||
            week.DateAndTime.Substring(0, 2) == "11" || week.DateAndTime.Substring(0, 2) == "12" || week.DateAndTime.Substring(0, 2) == "13" ||
            week.DateAndTime.Substring(0, 2) == "14")
            {
             countWeek2++;
            }else if(week.DateAndTime.Substring(0, 2) == "15" || week.DateAndTime.Substring(0, 2) == "16" || week.DateAndTime.Substring(0, 2) == "17" ||
            week.DateAndTime.Substring(0, 2) == "18" || week.DateAndTime.Substring(0, 2) == "19" || week.DateAndTime.Substring(0, 2) == "20" ||
            week.DateAndTime.Substring(0, 2) == "21")
           {
            countWeek3++;
           }
           else
           {
            countWeek4++;
           }
```

Comment: There are only 7 days in a week, not 31

Comment: You are looping through a week, but your "if" conditions are checking for all the days in a month.

Comment: what type is `week.DateAndTime` ?

Comment: Also: you won't see just the current month anymore after you have more than a year's worth of data. It's **NEVER** good when you find yourself using strings to do date checks.

Comment: is of type string

Answer (score 1):

not sure what the for loop is about ... not really sure what you want to have as a result ... but let me guess...

```
db.AllJobModel.Where(a=> a.Month == monthNow).ToList().GroupBy(x=>(int.Parse(x.DateAndtime.Substring(0,2))/7)+1).Select(x=>new { week = x.Key, sum=x.Sum()})
```

edit:

or the 4 week variant ...

```
db.AllJobModel.Where(a=> a.Month == monthNow).ToList().GroupBy(x=>(int.Parse(x.DateAndtime.Substring(0,2))/7)+1).Select(x=>new { week = x.Key <= 4 ? x.Key : 4, sum=x.Sum()})
```

Comment: almost, He wants only 4 weeks so dont forget to check for 5th week (days 29,30,31)
`db.AllJobModel.Where(a=> a.Month == monthNow).ToList().GroupBy(x => { int week = int.Parse(x.DateAndtime.Substring(0, 2)) / 7 + 1; return week > 4 ? 4 : week; }).Select(x=>new { week = x.Key, sum=x.Sum()})`

Comment: I understand that there is a bug with my code but the main issue that I am facing is to do with the time I think it matters in where the time format of the current computer

Comment: working with date and time as strings is a really bad idea in general. there are classes and structures for that... see DateTime

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through a week, but your "if" conditions are checking for all the days in a month.

> Can someone explains why

The reason the other values are 0 is because only "countWeek1" is incremented (Because you are looping through a week, not a month), thats why the rest are 0.

Comment: The core issue is to do I think with the time format of the computer because the format that I am getting through debugging is different from what is in the database